# How to flip an image with the HTML5 canvas without scaling

Tags: html, canvas, drawimage

I use the HTML5 canvas element to display an image in a web application and I want to flip the image horizontally *without* applying a scaling transformation to the canvas. This means that I do not want to use [CanvasRenderingContext2D.scale()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/scale) for this purpose, because I don't want to flip anything else.

```
// I don't want this, because it breaks the rest of the application. I have
// implemented zooming and landmark placement functionality, which no longer
// work properly after scaling.
ctx.save();
ctx.scale(-1, 1);
ctx.drawImage(image, -image.width, 0, image.width, image.height);
ctx.restore();
```

It seems to me that I should be able to do this with the [CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) method, since that page reads:

> sWidth: The width of the sub-rectangle of the source image to draw into the destination context. If not specified, the entire rectangle from the coordinates specified by sx and sy to the bottom-right corner of the image is used. **If you specify a negative value, the image is flipped horizontally when drawn.**

This is how I draw the image:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var image = document.getElementById('source');
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
```

Working example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage#Using_the_drawImage_method

But if I try to flip the image as per the description, I get the following error in Firefox:

```
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, -image.width, image.height, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
```

> IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed
>   amount

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here. How can I flip an image horizontally without scaling the canvas?

Comment: I made a mistake when I first tested with `scale()` and `restore()`. That actually works fine.

Comment: I updated the Mozilla page for `drawImage()`, since image flipping with negative values isn't mentioned in the specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Negative region does not seem to be supported (yet?), or **[this line may affect how the implementation is done, ref. step 4](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#dom-context-2d-drawimage)**:

> The image data must be processed in the original direction, even if
>   the dimensions given are negative.

In any case, we can't do much about it but to look at alternative ways -

This leaves you with some options though - I assume you want to avoid using save/restore, and you can -

**Reset transformation**

This is the fastest method, but you need to be aware of that it will reset any transformation. And this may be OK in most cases, so:

```
ctx.scale(-1, 1);
ctx.drawImage(image, -image.width, 0);
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
```

The last call is resetting the transformation matrix using an identity matrix.

**Reversing last transformation operation**

If you depend on other transformations, you can simply reverse the last transformation operation. This is the second fastest option (it need to do a matrix multiplication internally):

```
ctx.scale(-1, 1);
ctx.drawImage(image, -image.width, 0);
ctx.scale(-1, 1);   // revert scale only
```

**Using save/restore**

As you already know... but slow as it saves and restores the whole state of the canvas, not just the transformation.

**Flipping manually**

If there for some reason is a requirement not to use transformation at all, you can always flip it scanline by scanline. This is the second least efficient method but allows you to work without transformations, and it does allow you to do other things like displacing:

```
for(var x = 0; x < width; x++)
    ctx.drawImage(img, x, 0, 1, height, width - x, 0, 1, height);
```

(width and height being the image's width and height).

**Pixel manipulation**

And the last, just for the record, is of course to get the pixel data and loop through, switch places etc. This is the slowest method and it depends on CORS requirement, and is not recommended for this.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer Ken! I went with your first method. Turns out that scaling works fine after all, as long as you reset the transformation afterwards (I made a mistake when I first tested with `scale()` and `restore()`). And it seems that you are correct about the negative region; it isn't mentioned anywhere in the living HTML standard. That Mozilla page needs to be updated.

Answer (score 4):

A fairly simple solution would be to use a second canvas, draw the image there flipped only once, then draw that portion of the other canvas onto your main canvas. That would successfully create a flipped version of your image, cached, and you can draw it wherever you want.

Comment: Upvote for Good answer. And just to be clear...your second canvas can be an image source for your main canvas--no need to convert to an image. `mainContext.drawImage( flippingCanvas,125,50)`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer Eric! Your method works, but it gave other complications in my particular application (not your fault; still give you up vote). Ken's first method was easiest to implement, and didn't have side effects in my application.

Comment: Code example? I'd like to see how both canvases are implemented. At least, in the way that you would do it.