# How to draw one image multiple times in different direcitons?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have an array like this, the idea is to output images in different directions and flip them vertically and horizonatly on a canvas by scaling.

```
[{  
  "pos":{  
      "x":411,
      "y":401.5
  },
  "scale":{  
      "x":1,
      "y":1
  }
},{  
  "pos":{  
      "x":411,
      "y":271.59625
  },
  "scale":{  
      "x":-1,
      "y":1
  }
}]
```

The problem is that I'm scaling the canvas instead of the images, the canvas is multiple times bigger than the images i'm placing on it.

```
  images.forEach((image) => {
    // center borde köars innan loopen egentligen
    let pos = center(image.pos)
    cc.save()
    cc.scale(image.scale.x, image.scale.y)
    cc.drawImage(window.video, pos.x, pos.y)
    cc.restore()
  })
```

How do I scale the image, called window.video, instead of the entire canvas?

Answer (score 0):

To render a scaled image on the canvas.

```
function drawImage(image,x,y,scaleX,scaleY){
    ctx.setTransform(scaleX, 0, 0, scaleY, x, y); // set scale and translation
    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
}

// when done drawing images you need to reset the transformation back to default
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // set default transform
```

If you want the image flipped but still drawn at the same top left position use

```
function drawImage(image, x, y, scaleX, scaleY){
    ctx.setTransform(scaleX, 0, 0, scaleY, x, y); // set scale and translation
    x = scaleX < 0 ? -image.width : 0; // move drawing position if flipped
    y = scaleY < 0 ? -image.height : 0;
    ctx.drawImage(image, x, y);
}
```

And to draw about the center of the image

```
function drawImage(image, x, y, scaleX, scaleY){  // x y define center
    ctx.setTransform(scaleX, 0, 0, scaleY, x, y); // set scale and translation
    ctx.drawImage(image, -image.width / 2, -image.height / 2);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: As noted below, this doesn't work with negative values...

drawImage can take 2 extra arguments for sizing the image, so the following should work:

```
images.forEach((image) => {
  // center borde köars innan loopen
  let pos = center(image.pos)
  cc.save()
  cc.drawImage(window.video, pos.x, pos.y, window.video.width * image.scale.x, window.video.height * image.scale.y)
  cc.restore()
})
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images

Comment: I tried it, but those only work for positive numbers and don't seem to work for scale. I found this question, but don't rellay get how I could use those answers either http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29237305/how-to-flip-an-image-with-the-html5-canvas-without-scaling

Comment: If you use your original code but specify the width and height in drawImage to be the window.video height and width does that work?

Comment: yes it would but I want negative values on dWidth and dHeight, so I can't use those. dWidth and dHeight only work on positive values.